# split table after values of specific row

Tags: sql, postgresql

postgres table 'mytable'  has columns 'a','b','c' and 'mycol'.

how can I split the table efficiently, so that all entries having value 'x' in 'mycol' get in one table ('mytableX'), those with value 'y' in another ('mytableY')and those with value 'z' ('mytableZ') in another.

can this be done in pure sql?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, rather than just using a `where` clause when you need it?

Comment: some interface issues, I'm aware it sounds dumb but this is the usual way I have to provide data in my case.

Comment: PostgreSQL documentation is quite detailed with regard of how to do this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can do:

```
create table mytableX as
    select * from mytable where mycol = 'X';
```

You would repeat this for each table.

Having said that, there are very few reasons why you would want to do this.  Splitting a table is unlikely to make queries more efficient; it increases the number of tables; the new tables can get out-of-date from the larger tables; and so on.

I can only think of one good reason.  That would be to provide separate access controls for each table.  Even in this case, there are other options, but splitting the data into separate tables can simplify security.

If you really need something like this, views are probably a better approach than separate tables:

```
create view mytableX as
    select * from mytable where mycol = 'X';
```